# Jquery Ajax : permanent function on selector?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a problem using same time a plugin for tooltips on links and ajax call (that produce other links). I would like my tooltip plugin to work for all my links, but new links called by ajax, are not working with the plugin, it's only working for the normal links (without ajax calls).

This is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        //Initialization for the tooltip plugin
        $(function(){
            $(".tooltip").tipTip();
        });

        //Code for Ajax requests
        $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
        var nom = $(this).attr("value");
        if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
          var target_url = "cgi-bin/switch.pl?param=" + $(this).attr('value');
          $('<div id="target_' + $(this).val() + '" class="haut"></div>')
          .html('<img src="ressources/ajax-loader.gif" />') 
          .load(target_url)
          .appendTo('#target');
          $("a").wTooltip();
        }
        else {
          $('div#target_' + $(this).attr('value')).remove();
        }
    })
});
```

The code for the tooltip plugin is [tiptip](http://code.google.com/p/ss-scrum-tool/source/browse/trunk/www/public/javascripts/jquery.tipTip.js?r=1656), it's a function definition.

How can I modify my jquery script to allow tooltip to work on links from ajax requests ??
Thanks.
Bye.

Edit : I found how to do : add a callback function in .load() :

```
.load(target_url, function() { $(".tooltip").tipTip(); })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the live function...

http://api.jquery.com/live/

I havnt had time to test this but I had a quick go at updating TipTip to use the live function...

```
/*
 * TipTip
 * Copyright 2010 Drew Wilson
 * www.drewwilson.com
 * code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin
 *
 * Version 1.3   -   Updated: Mar. 23, 2010
 *
 * This Plug-In will create a custom tooltip to replace the default
 * browser tooltip. It is extremely lightweight and very smart in
 * that it detects the edges of the browser window and will make sure
 * the tooltip stays within the current window size. As a result the
 * tooltip will adjust itself to be displayed above, below, to the left 
 * or to the right depending on what is necessary to stay within the
 * browser window. It is completely customizable as well via CSS.
 *
 * This TipTip jQuery plug-in is dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 */

(function($){
    $.fn.tipTip = function(options) {
        var defaults = { 
            activation: "hover",
            keepAlive: false,
            maxWidth: "200px",
            edgeOffset: 3,
            defaultPosition: "bottom",
            delay: 400,
            fadeIn: 200,
            fadeOut: 200,
            attribute: "title",
            content: false, // HTML or String to fill TipTIp with
            enter: function(){},
            exit: function(){}
        };
        var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);

        // Setup tip tip elements and render them to the DOM
        if($("#tiptip_holder").length <= 0){
            var tiptip_holder = $('<div id="tiptip_holder" style="max-width:'+ opts.maxWidth +';"></div>');
            var tiptip_content = $('<div id="tiptip_content"></div>');
            var tiptip_arrow = $('<div id="tiptip_arrow"></div>');
            $("body").append(tiptip_holder.html(tiptip_content).prepend(tiptip_arrow.html('<div id="tiptip_arrow_inner"></div>')));
        } else {
            var tiptip_holder = $("#tiptip_holder");
            var tiptip_content = $("#tiptip_content");
            var tiptip_arrow = $("#tiptip_arrow");
        }

        return this.each(function(){
            var org_elem = $(this);
            if(opts.content){
                var org_title = opts.content;
            } else {
                var org_title = org_elem.attr(opts.attribute);
            }
            if(org_title != ""){
                if(!opts.content){
                    org_elem.removeAttr(opts.attribute); //remove original Attribute
                }
                var timeout = false;

                if(opts.activation == "hover"){
                    org_elem.live('hover', function(){
                        active_tiptip();
                    }, function(){
                        if(!opts.keepAlive){
                            deactive_tiptip();
                        }
                    });
                    if(opts.keepAlive){
                        tiptip_holder.live('hover', function(){}, function(){
                            deactive_tiptip();
                        });
                    }
                } else if(opts.activation == "focus"){
                    org_elem.live('focus', function(){
                        active_tiptip();
                    }).blur(function(){
                        deactive_tiptip();
                    });
                } else if(opts.activation == "click"){
                    org_elem.live('click', function(){
                        active_tiptip();
                        return false;
                    }).live('hover', function(){},function(){
                        if(!opts.keepAlive){
                            deactive_tiptip();
                        }
                    });
                    if(opts.keepAlive){
                        tiptip_holder.live('hover', function(){}, function(){
                            deactive_tiptip();
                        });
                    }
                }

                function active_tiptip(){
                    opts.enter.call(this);
                    tiptip_content.html(org_title);
                    tiptip_holder.hide().removeAttr("class").css("margin","0");
                    tiptip_arrow.removeAttr("style");

                    var top = parseInt(org_elem.offset()['top']);
                    var left = parseInt(org_elem.offset()['left']);
                    var org_width = parseInt(org_elem.outerWidth());
                    var org_height = parseInt(org_elem.outerHeight());
                    var tip_w = tiptip_holder.outerWidth();
                    var tip_h = tiptip_holder.outerHeight();
                    var w_compare = Math.round((org_width - tip_w) / 2);
                    var h_compare = Math.round((org_height - tip_h) / 2);
                    var marg_left = Math.round(left + w_compare);
                    var marg_top = Math.round(top + org_height + opts.edgeOffset);
                    var t_class = "";
                    var arrow_top = "";
                    var arrow_left = Math.round(tip_w - 12) / 2;

                    if(opts.defaultPosition == "bottom"){
                        t_class = "_bottom";
                    } else if(opts.defaultPosition == "top"){ 
                        t_class = "_top";
                    } else if(opts.defaultPosition == "left"){
                        t_class = "_left";
                    } else if(opts.defaultPosition == "right"){
                        t_class = "_right";
                    }

                    var right_compare = (w_compare + left) < parseInt($(window).scrollLeft());
                    var left_compare = (tip_w + left) > parseInt($(window).width());

                    if((right_compare && w_compare < 0) || (t_class == "_right" && !left_compare) || (t_class == "_left" && left < (tip_w + opts.edgeOffset + 5))){
                        t_class = "_right";
                        arrow_top = Math.round(tip_h - 13) / 2;
                        arrow_left = -12;
                        marg_left = Math.round(left + org_width + opts.edgeOffset);
                        marg_top = Math.round(top + h_compare);
                    } else if((left_compare && w_compare < 0) || (t_class == "_left" && !right_compare)){
                        t_class = "_left";
                        arrow_top = Math.round(tip_h - 13) / 2;
                        arrow_left =  Math.round(tip_w);
                        marg_left = Math.round(left - (tip_w + opts.edgeOffset + 5));
                        marg_top = Math.round(top + h_compare);
                    }

                    var top_compare = (top + org_height + opts.edgeOffset + tip_h + 8) > parseInt($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop());
                    var bottom_compare = ((top + org_height) - (opts.edgeOffset + tip_h + 8)) < 0;

                    if(top_compare || (t_class == "_bottom" && top_compare) || (t_class == "_top" && !bottom_compare)){
                        if(t_class == "_top" || t_class == "_bottom"){
                            t_class = "_top";
                        } else {
                            t_class = t_class+"_top";
                        }
                        arrow_top = tip_h;
                        marg_top = Math.round(top - (tip_h + 5 + opts.edgeOffset));
                    } else if(bottom_compare | (t_class == "_top" && bottom_compare) || (t_class == "_bottom" && !top_compare)){
                        if(t_class == "_top" || t_class == "_bottom"){
                            t_class = "_bottom";
                        } else {
                            t_class = t_class+"_bottom";
                        }
                        arrow_top = -12;                        
                        marg_top = Math.round(top + org_height + opts.edgeOffset);
                    }

                    if(t_class == "_right_top" || t_class == "_left_top"){
                        marg_top = marg_top + 5;
                    } else if(t_class == "_right_bottom" || t_class == "_left_bottom"){     
                        marg_top = marg_top - 5;
                    }
                    if(t_class == "_left_top" || t_class == "_left_bottom"){    
                        marg_left = marg_left + 5;
                    }
                    tiptip_arrow.css({"margin-left": arrow_left+"px", "margin-top": arrow_top+"px"});
                    tiptip_holder.css({"margin-left": marg_left+"px", "margin-top": marg_top+"px"}).attr("class","tip"+t_class);

                    if (timeout){ clearTimeout(timeout); }
                    timeout = setTimeout(function(){ tiptip_holder.stop(true,true).fadeIn(opts.fadeIn); }, opts.delay); 
                }

                function deactive_tiptip(){
                    opts.exit.call(this);
                    if (timeout){ clearTimeout(timeout); }
                    tiptip_holder.fadeOut(opts.fadeOut);
                }
            }               
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: @Dean North : Already tried, doesn't work. Explain your solution... to you, where to add .live() ?

Comment: @Dean North : Thx, but it doesn't work, no more tooltip at all.

Comment: I just realised that .live doesnt work with .hover, instead you need to do mouseover and mouseout separately. If you can give me the example html you are using I will try to get it to work for you.

Comment: I use tiptip on links like : `<a title="&lt;b&gt;Port : FastEthernet0/13&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br/&gt;Index 10013 sur VLAN : 1&lt;br/&gt;@mac : 1C6F65884F27&lt;br/&gt;Vitesse=100 Mbps Alias=SR1 B13&lt;br/&gt; Full duplex
" class="tooltip"><img alt="port n°13" src="ressources/interface_haut_up.png" /> 
</a>`

Comment: That's ok, found how to do. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it to work. Can you post your solution to help others in the future.